# Move EditText to specific position

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

I have an EditText in a RelativeLayout, and I wanted to dynamically position it (at runtime), with a rotation if possible. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

For repositioning you can use `setTranslationX()` and `setTranslationY()`.
For rotation use `setRotation()`.
You can find more info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: Is EditText an extension of a View? Because I can't see those methods, I can use setTransformationMethod(), would that do the trick?

Comment: Yes, EditText extends View as you can see here and has these methods: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

Comment: android 3.0 + will allow such methods, #J-P

Comment: @Rotem, I am also going to move/rotate textview position by user,
would you guide me to quick approach for setting rotation, as I am not getting what angles degree user will rotate the view, so I can call view.setRotation(angleDegreeFloatValue);

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question - do you want to rotate the view as a response to a touch event? if so, you should calculate the distance between the point of the ACTION_DOWN MotionEvent and the ACTION_MOVE, and manipulate with that the degree value. the numbers that you will choose to multiply will define the sensibility of the rotation